# how to run bash script interactively from url?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script called myscript.sh, containing a prompt like this:

`read -p "Press enter to continue"`

If I run it from a prompt "`bash myscript.sh`" I get the prompt as expected

But if I run it via a pipeline, "`cat myscript.sh | bash`"  I don't get the prompt

The end goal is to execute it remotely from a webserver like so:

`wget myhost.com/myscript.sh -O -|bash`

or

`curl myhost.com/myscript.sh | bash`

But in those cases I don't get the prompt because it's pipelined.

How can I run it remotely and get the prompt?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a full script that allows the problem (mvtc)

Comment: In steps: 1. Download it to a file. 2. Run `bash file`. `an I run it remotely` What does it mean "run remotely"? What is "remote" here?

Comment: @KamilCuk  was trying to eliminate 2 steps. are you sure there isn't a flag to curl or wget or bash to enable me to do that in a single step?

Comment: @KamilCuk by "remotely" I mean I want to execute the script that exists on a webserver, as shown with the wget/curl examples above, without downloading it locally first

Comment: A single step is possible if you `eval` the result of the `curl` command, but I have to say that's a little insane o_O `eval "$(curl myhost.com/myscript.sh)"`

Comment: Note that from a security perspective, this is a Really Bad Idea. (All of it, including the `curl | sh` pattern)

Comment: If you want to read the prompt from the interactive console, rather than from stdin, that would look like `read -p "Press enter to continue" </dev/tty` -- though this only works when run from a context that _has_ a TTY, options to function where one isn't available will be strictly worse (less portable, with more surprising corner cases).